# Unable to find or obtain a context for request certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send push notification to iphone. By searching on internet i found that register the P12 file on server with winhttpcertcfg. But when I tried with this command

winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "CertificateName" -a "ASPNET"

on command window after installing winhttpcertcfg.

But I am getting the error "Unable to find or obtain a context for request certificate"

Can you please suggest me, how to solve this error?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed. I am running into the same problem

Answer (score 2):

1. Open MMC console
2. Add Certificates snap-in for "Computer Account". Next.
3. Select "Local Computer". Next
4. Locate "Personal\Certificates".
5. Open context menu on this folder. Select Tasks\Import.
6. Find your p12 certificate. Next
7. Find password in "certificate name".ks.pw.txt file and use it. Next
8. Next. Finish.

Open cmd as Administrator.

Locate **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools** for x64 machine

or **C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools** on x86 machine

Run the following commands sequentially. This match the IIS 6-7.5

**winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s CERTIFICATE NAME -a YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME**

**winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s CERTIFICATE NAME -a YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME\IIS_IUSRS**

**winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s CERTIFICATE NAME -a YOUR_COMPUTER_NAME\IUSR**

**winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s CERTIFICATE NAME -a NetworkService**

if everything ok you will see messages like
Granting private key access for account: ...

Perhaps after that you will have to wait for few minutes due to windows stuffs. In my case certificates was not applied immediately.

If you did everything correct, browser and navigate to **https://ws.merchanttest.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl**

you will see the following (my case)

[image]

click OK, and you get the WSDL schema.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check if you certificate resides in "MY" certification store.