# unable to find or obtain a context for requested certificate

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-server-2008, winhttpcertcfg

Whole day I am trying to install a firstdata payment certificate, I inserted the certificate in the Personal folder under Certificates with mmc.
Now running the winhttpcertcfg.exe console app, I am getting an error saying:
unable to find or obtain a context for requested certificate.

This is the command I am using:

winhttpcertcfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s WS101..1 -a IWAM_B3B

I was browsing Google for some time now without any success.
Every comment is more then welcome.
Thanks, Laziale

Comment: Find my answer if still actual http://stackoverflow.com/a/15708238/344895

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and finally I found out that my certificate was installed in the CURRENT_USER store and not in the LOCAL_MACHINE one.

**winhttpcertcfg -l -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s "Issued To"** was throwing the "Unable to find or obtain a context for requested certificate" error while 
**winhttpcertcfg -l -c CURRENT_USER\My -s "Issued To"** returned the certicate's details.

After I had added the cetificate to the correct place via mmc.exe (Snap-in Certificates for Computer account - Local computer), I was able to grant private key access for the required account (NetworkService in my case).